# Exception handling in power apps for runtime exceptions

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

Basic app layout:
I created a sample power app where I just took around 20 text inputs collecting the data from it and sending it to the power automate flow (I am not using data card and form).

Now,
I handled the exceptions in the power automate flow as any flow functionality got failed we should get a custom message in power apps; it is successfully working.

but I am looking for something like,

- what if the power app didn't get any response because of timeout.(2 min is the timeout limit for "**respond to the power app or flow**" action.)?
- what if the power automate flow is turned of?
- what if the internet connection is broken while operating the app?
- what if the flow abruptly failed/canceled?

how could I handle these runtime exceptions.
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can implement error handling on two levels:

1. Wrapping your logic in IfError() function to handle a specific error ([see Shane's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUk7krgitzw))
2. Define general error handling in the App.OnError property ([another explanation by Shane](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zc4mE_4U7lI))

To tackle broken connections, check out the [Connection() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/signals#connection).

Comment: @mmikesy90mmik I will check out your suggestions, thanks for the response